# How do I improve my ETL performance?

Tags: etl, rdbms, data-warehouse

Background Info:

I have a tradition ETL (on SQL Server) which takes around 6 hours to complete. I am looking to optimise the ETL. Below are the steps I have already taken:

1. Removed unnecessary CURSOR from the logic. For the remaining one's that I am not able to remove, I used READ_ONLY, FAST_FORWARD, INSENSITIVE.
2. There was some sorting of data happening, which I removed.
3. Tune the SQL Queries that were long running by using compiler hints or Join hints.
4. Removed unnecessary columns that were being fetched from source.
5. Partitioned the tables as well. I use partition switch which did improve some performance.

Is there any other method I am missing which could help make the ETL faster? At this point, we don't have the option of adding more powerful hardware resources or migrating into Hadoop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not a lot of info to go with. What kind of operations are you using? Do you know which parts of the process take the longest time? Can you post any relevant code?

Comment: What ETL tool are you using?

Comment: No custom ETL tool like informatica or Appworx. ETL is custom written using SQL Stored procedures and Unix Shell script. The finance part takes the longest time. Do you want the entire code of the etl?

Comment: OK that sheds a _little_ more light on your situation. Does your ETL load _all_ history or just the current period? Don't post _all_ the code. Take the next step and identify which part of your code is slowest and consider posting that. If you just post a wall of code that's not going to help. Oh and you need to tag the RDBMS (Oracle, SQL Server etc.)

Comment: ETL does load all the history but only for finance rest is an incremental load. As you suggested I will post the long running scripts.

Comment: If finance takes the longest and it's the only thing that's not an incremental load then that might be a place to start. Please also tag the RDBMS. Why ask a SQL question without indicating the platform?

Answer (score 0):

Few questions:
Are your sources SQL Server databases? 
Have you reviewed your destination database? 
Is this a dimensional datawarehouse or a normalised data store?

Without much knowledge on your source and destination, some other things I might recommend:

1)Remove unwanted lookup transformations, if you have any.

2)If you can afford to, I would look at creating indexes on some of your source tables. Not always feasible, but this helps believe me.

3)Remove unwanted UNIONs

If its possible please share further info on your ETL/Database architecture and I am sure many brains over here would be able to shed more wisdom.

Cheers
Nithin